# How to Handle page onload alert in Selenium IDE?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I am submitting a page and I have a Confirmation alert which is working great; The on successful submit when the new page loads I get another alert notification just to say the successful message.
assertAlert for this second alert generates There were no Alerts error for me. I tried other ways like waitforPageload, chooseOkOnNextConfirmation with no luck.
I have seen that it is noted that if the alert fires on page load there is no way to handle it. Just wondering if there is any suggestions or work around to manage the situation ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using assertConfirmation command with target as 'message in the pop-up'.